# iOS Offline data buffer

Tags: ios, iphone

Greeting everyone,

I am looking for a simple way to but my data in a buffer if I ever don't have access to Internet for a certain time.

Lets take a GSP app as an example: I am somewhere with no cell tower but my GPS registers my location. Then when I gain Internet back, it will send these location to the server.

I am currently using restkit to post my objects to the server. When the object is sent to the server, I don't really need it on the phone. So in a way I don't need a 1:1 sync between the iphone and the rest api.

The only idea I have is to have a simple local database (SQLite ?) and monitoring the connection, So I insert in the database when its offline and as soon as the connection is back up, I send the rows and delete them from the local database.

Anyone has a better idea?

Thank you

Jonathan

Comment: you should explain your purpose and be less vague when asking. its hard to tell what you want

Comment: You already describe a solution, go implement it (probably with Core Data as the store).